# Overlap charts in SSRS show just one chart area

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i'm following this [Tutorial](http://www.angelsbiblog.com/2012/02/improve-data-visualization-in-your-ssrs.html) to build a overlaped report, but no matters what i do, just one chart color has been showed, i cant make this style: [image]:

Did someone had the same issue ?

Thnks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **PointWidth** Property for each of your series. The top series should have a smaller width than the bottom (underneath) series. If the widths are the same for both series, you would only see the top series.

Comment: Yes, I check and the PointWidth is not the same, like the tutorial told me to do :(

Comment: Hmm - one other thing to try. Change the order of the series to make sure that the smaller one isn't behind the other series. "locate the **ChartAreas** property in the Property... Hit the ellipse button and you can reorder which Chart Area comes in front." Sometimes it's quicker to start over than troubleshoot. :(

Comment: They are not the same size, but only the one which comes in front appears.